# Is there a performance penalty on remote hosting StatsD?

Tags: php, performance, udp, statsd

I am setting up StatsD/Graphite for monitoring my PHP based web application. Graphite is installed on a remote server, and will aggregate data from 2 different servers. For StatsD, I could install it on the same server where Graphite is installed, or I could the server where web application servers.

Is there a performance penalty for the web application, when the web application and the StatsD server are on different hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: Absolutely **none**!

Longer:

The UDP protocol being used to communicate with StatsD, the client (your PHP application in this case) will even not know whether the packets sent are received or not because UDP is **connection-less**!

Whatever the technology (StatsD or not), UDP always means that there is no performance penalty whether the receiver is distant or not, or even if the receiver exists/is up.